# How to parse JSON in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a json like below.

```
 private _ELEMENT_DATA: Account[] = [ 
  {"id":{"name":"abc", "value":"123"}},
  {"id":{"name":"abc", "value":"123"}},
  {"id":{"name":"abc", "value":"123"}}
 ]
```

Please help me how to parse in Angular 6

```
export class Account{
 name: string;
 value: string;
}
```

My service class has like this

```
getAllAccouts(): Observable<any[]> {
// return this.httpClient.get<Account[]>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
return of<Account[]>(this._ELEMENT_DATA);
}
```

Comment: you need an outer class, `export class Outer { id: Account }`, then change every reference of `Account[]` to `Outer[]` or whatever you want to name your new class

Comment: Unless `new Account` happens somewhere that Account class is never used, you should use interface to strongly type object literal. Also there is no JSON in this example only javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a result that matches your class `Account`, first of all, your "json", which is in fact a JS array, cannot have the type `Account[]`, so that has to be either a model that holds your `Account` objects. Here I borrow the model by Jamie:

```ts
export interface AccountContainer {
  id: Account;
}

export interface Account {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

private _ELEMENT_DATA: AccountContainer[] = [
  { "id": { "name": "abc", "value": "123" } },
  { "id": { "name": "abc", "value": "123" } },
  { "id": { "name": "abc", "value": "123" } }
]
```

Also, since you have no constructor, or methods for your class, an interface would suffice. So to get your desired result do:

```ts
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ....

getAllAccouts(): Observable<Account[]> {
  return of<AccountContainer[]>(this._ELEMENT_DATA).pipe(
    map(x => x.map(y => <Account>{ name: y.id.name, value: y.id.value }))
  )
}
```

With that, you get an array of objects matching your `Account` interface.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it was suitable for you! :) if it helped you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

That JSON will not be able to be parsed to the class.

You need a class like this:

```
export class AccountContainer {
    id: Account;
}
```

and change your service code to the following:

```
getAllAccouts(): Observable<AccountContainer[]> {
    return of<AccountContainer[]>(this._ELEMENT_DATA);
}
```

Comment: I need name and value, not Account object.

Comment: @sree1611 Your question was how to parse the JSON. I have given you an example on how to parse it. You would then access the account object by doing `accountContainer.id` <- That would be the `AccountClass` then

Comment: The elements of the result of getAllAccouts() would not be `res[0] instanceof AccountContainer`, should use `interface AccountContainer` and `interface Account`.